# crop an image responsively keeping the center of the image visible (horizontally)

Tags: jquery, css, image, wordpress, center

Here is the website I need help with: www.aaronrhoades.com/blog
The header image grows when it's on a bigger browser (e.g. on a TV screen) and shrinks when it's on a smaller browser. BUT, it stops shrinking at a certain point because I don't want it to get too small.

**The problem:** once the image stops shrinking then it stays glued in one spot horizontally based on the left side of the image. I want it to move left so that the logo stays visible. Something like a "margin-left:-50%;" would work for mobile, but obviously that messes it up on a full screen.

CSS only would be great if possible, otherwise I am ok with jquery. PHP might be good since this is a wordpress, I'm just not too familiar with it. Here is my code:

```
 #nicelogo{
    overflow:hidden;
 }
 #nicelogo img{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 683px;
    min-height: 250px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
 }
```

and the html:

```
<div id="header"> 
<div id="nicelogo">
<img src="http://www.aaronrhoades.com/images/web-header-home.jpg" width="1366" height="500">
</div>!-- end of #nicelogo -->
</div>!-- end of #header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 683px) {
    #nicelogo img{
        margin-left: 50%;
        left: -341px;
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

use css media query

Comment: Thank you so much! did not know about the css @media queries. 
The only few things I had to change were 1: the "left" (because I realized my logo was not directly in the center of the picture. I might end up changing that in the picture itself though)
and 2: had to give the "nicelogo" div a min-height because otherwise the page would fall apart when position:absolute; was applied.

This works great and I will be doing more research on this feature. Thanks again.

Comment: I wish I could upvote your comment but I just joined, sorry. :P